# Explicit bound on $\zeta(s)$ inside the critical strip?

Tags: reference-request, riemann-zeta

Does anybody know of a place in the literature where one can find an *explicit* result of the form $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|\leq C \log t$ for $t$ within a zero-free region (assuming $t$ is larger than an explicit constant)?

There is Theorem 6.25 in

https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/mark.coleman/old/MATH41022/Present/Notes/Notes%206d%20PNT%202018-19.pdf

-- that is exactly the sort of result I'm looking for, but I'd prefer to refer to something that has been actually published (or at least put on the arxiv).

This kind of result is not at all hard, but it would make no sense to prove it from scratch (given that it must have been proved many times before).